# How to specify routing for a child component of a child component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      title: 'Purchase'
    },
    children: [    
      {
        path: 'list-vendor',
        component: VendorsListComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'List Vendors',
        },
        children: [    
          {
            path: 'create-vendor/:id',
            component: CreateVendorComponent,
            data: {
              title: 'Vendor'
            }
          }
        ]    
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here routing for CretateVendorComponent is not working,I'm getting 404 error but if I comment out routing for inner children,routing for outer one (VendorListComponent)is working perfectly...How to specify routing for child component of a child component?

Answer (score 0):

The current url to `CreateVendorComponent` is

```
/list-vendor/create-vendor/:id
```

Where `:id` should be replaced by some parameter.

What url are you using?

This path is built up from each subsequent node as you traverse down the hierarchy:

- path = `''`
- VendorsListComponent - path = `'list-vendor'`
- CreateVendorComponent - path = `'create-vendor/:id'`

Comment: Url I'm using is `purchase/list-vendor/create-vendor/0` but getting 404

Comment: Exactly. The path of the first parent is `''`, not `'purchase'`.

Comment: Have you made a mistake copying in your routes? Or is this a child module?

Answer (score 0):

You could play around module routing.

app-routing.module.ts

```
 {
     path: 'list-vendor',
     loadChildren: '{PATH_TO_YOUR_MODULE}#{MODULE_NAME}'
 }
```

Vendors.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '',
        component: VendorsListComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'create-vendor/:id',
        component: CreateVendorComponent
    }
]),
```